# Combining Predicates

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming, predicate

Is there any way that you can combine predicates?

Lets say I have something like this:

```
class MatchBeginning : public binary_function<CStdString, CStdString, bool>
{   public:
          bool operator()(const CStdString &inputOne, const CStdString &inputTwo) const
    {   return inputOne.substr(0, inputTwo.length()).compare(inputTwo) == 0;    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CStdString myString("foo -b ar -t az"); 

    vector<CStdString> tokens;

    // splits the string every time it encounters a "-"
    split(myString, tokens, "-", true, true);   

    vector<CStdString>::iterator searchResult = find_if(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), not1(bind2nd(MatchBeginning(), "-")));        

    return 0;
}
```

This works, but now I'd like to do something like:

```
searchResult = find_if(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), bind2nd(MatchBeginning(), "-b") || not1(bind2nd(MatchBeginning(), "-")));
```

So I'd like to find the first string that starts with "-b" or the first string that does not start with "-". However, this gives me an error (binary '||' undefined).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can recommend boost.lambda for combining function-objects for such tasks.  Although it is a bit heavyweight for such a simple problem.  (**edit**) See the community wiki answer started by xhantt for a good example using STL.

(old, deprecated, answer) You can write your own utility for this, similar:

```
// here we define the combiner...
template<class Left, class Right>
class lazy_or_impl {
  Left m_left;
  Right m_right;
public:
  lazy_or_impl(Left const& left, Right const& right) : m_left(left), m_right(right) {}
  typename Left::result_type operator()(typename Left::argument_type const& a) const {
    return m_left(a) || m_right(a);
  }
};

// and a helper function which deduces the template arguments
// (thx to xtofl to point this out)
template<class Left, class Right>
lazy_or_impl<Left, Right> lazy_or(Left const& left, Right const& right) {
  return lazy_or_impl<Left, Right>(left, right);
}
```

and then use it: `... lazy_or(bind1st(...), bind1st(...)) ...`

Comment: You probably would need a shim function for that to compile, too: there is no template argument inference for classes.

Answer (score 5):

Well you have [std::logical_or](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/logical_or.html) and [std::compose2](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binary_compose.html) that can do the job

```
find_if(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), 
  compose2(logical_or<bool>(),
    bind2nd(MatchBeginning(), "-b"),
    bind2nd(MatchBeginning(), "-")
  ) 
);
```

but I think that boost::lambda and/or phoenix are more readable in the end, and are my recommended solution.

Credits should go to SGI documentation.

Comment: I knew that I've forgotten the obvious compose.  I just found logical_or, and just didn't remember it :-(

Comment: The problem with compose2 is that it is not part of the current C++ standard.

Comment: Well, neither boost::lambda nor phoenix are part of the standard, yet.

Comment: I know, I meant that it is pretty clear where to get the lambda and phoenix from, while for compose2 it's not that clear (some compilers have it, some not, etc).

Comment: But still think that boost::lambda is more readable and compact in the end, and if I can use boost the I will use it for sure.

Comment: But sometimes in a compiler with limited resources it is easier to get compose2 working than the full boost::lambda.

Comment: It is easier to hack your own version once you know how it is supposed to work.

Comment: All the comments are valid - everything depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compose predicates, the nicest way to write it is probably using the Boost Lambda or Boost Phoenix:

```
// Lambda way:
// Needs:
// #include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
// #include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    foo_vec::const_iterator it
        = std::find_if(
                    tokens.begin(),
                    tokens.end(),
                    bind(MatchBeginning(), _1, "-b") || !bind(MatchBeginning(), _1, "-")
                    );
}
// Boost bind way:
// Needs:
// #include <boost/bind.hpp>
{
    foo_vec::const_iterator it
        = std::find_if(
                    tokens.begin(),
                    tokens.end(),
                    boost::bind(
                                std::logical_or<bool>(),
                                boost::bind(MatchBeginning(), _1, "-b"),
                                !boost::bind(MatchBeginning(), _1, "-") // ! overloaded in bind
                               )
                    );
```

For the Phoenix way one of the possibilities is to use phoenix lazy functions, and the solution could look similar to the one below:

```
// Requires:
// #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
// #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_function.hpp>
// #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

struct match_beginning_impl
{
    template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
    struct result
    {
        typedef bool type;
    };

    template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
    bool operator()(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) const
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
};
phx::function<match_beginning_impl> match_beginning;

using phx::arg_names::arg1;

foo_vec::const_iterator it
    = std::find_if(
                tokens.begin(),
                tokens.end(),
                match_beginning(arg1, "-b") || !match_beginning(arg1, "-")
                );
```

However to accomplish your task it probably makes more sense to employ different tools - for example: regular expressions (Boost Regex or Boost Xpressive). If you want to handle the command line options then use Boost Program Options.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers for this question. In the end I found the non-library way the most interesting. Still, thanks for putting in the time to write out these snippets.